# How to use INDEX when applying an IF and not a MATCH?

Tags: indexing, match, coordinates, libreoffice-calc

I have two datasets in LibreOffice Calc containing the Cartesian coordinates of objects in a plane. One is old data with X number of objects, the other is newer data with the same X objects + N new ones.

Excel Spreadsheet:

```
      A          B          C          D     ||    E       F        G
      |          |          |          |     ||    |       |        |
1 - New ID  Previous ID  X Value    Y Value  || Old ID  X Value  Y Value
2 -  1a          ?        89.09      73.79   ||   1a     52.60    94.15 
3 -  1b          ?        52.50      94.05   ||   1b     81.20    28.49
4 -  1c          ?        36.72      94.85   ||   2a     91.04    38.93
5 -  2a          ?        81.14      28.38   ||   3a     68.65    84.64
6 -  2b          ?        07.50      46.69   ||   3b     64.50    37.18
7 -  3a          ?        90.72      39.00   ||   4a     18.36    03.65
```

For each old object's coordinates (columns F and G), I want to go through all the new objects' coordinates (columns C and D) and see if the distance *d* between the two is very small (for me a value of less than `1` will suffice).

```
d = SQRT( (X2-X1)^2 + (Y2-Y1)^2 )
```

If *d* < 1 then this means that they are the same object and I want to record its `Old ID` in column B.

```
=IF(SQRT((C2-$F$2)^2+(D2-$G$2)^2)<1,$E$2,0)
```

The above formula works for one object at a time when I click and drag until an ID appears; however, I have to copy and paste things around a lot to keep doing this method. The problem is that I have about 260 new objects to search through for around 180 old objects. Manual click-and-drag is too laborious.

I haven't been able to come up with a way to use VLOOKUP or INDEX to tell Excel "For these X and Y values in cells F2 and G2, go check the values in C2 and D2. If d is < 1 then print E2. If not go check F3 and G3 and print E3 if it's true *et cetera et cetera* until you find a match."

Does anyone have any advice on how to get this to work?

I know if the coordinates were *exactly* the same for an object in the old and new data then I could just use an INDEX MATCH combination but unfortunately they do differ slightly.

Answer (score 4):

In cell B2 and copied down you'll need one of these two formulas.  I'm a little fuzzy on exactly what you're looking for, but I am confident that one of these will fit:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($E$2:$E$7,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(SQRT((C2-$F$2:$F$7)^2+(D2-$G$2:$G$7)^2)<1,),0)),"No Match")
```

Or:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($E$2:$E$7,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(SQRT(($C$2:$C$7-F2)^2+($D$2:$D$7-G2)^2)<1,),0)),"No match")
```

Comment: Hey tigeravatar - Snap! you beat me by 3 seconds....and included error checking, I forgot about that.....btw I think it's the first one

Comment: Wow, yeah, exactly the same solution, haha!

Comment: @tigeravatar @barryh Did you test out your formulae on my sample data? The equations don't seem to work on my end.

The terms inside your square roots `$F2:$F$7` select whichever cell in that range is in the row currently being looked at, i.e. `C4-$F$2:$F$7` is the same as `C4-F4`. Does `MATCH` search through the range `$F$2:$F$7` because the only error I can think of is that the whole column is not being checked, only the corresponding cell in the row being looked at.

I am using LibreOffice but these formulae rules don't differ between it and Excel...

Comment: The formula certainly works in Excel, it needs to be "array entered" - I believe you can use such formulas in Libre Office but I can try a test shortly....by using C4-$F$2:$F$7 you get an array of 6 results, one for each row in F2:F7, and then MATCH finds the first row where your condition is true

Comment: Sorry, we used a construction which avoids array entry ( an extra INDEX function) so you don,t need to array enter in excel......but Libre Office might not work the same in that regard - let me check

Comment: I tried the formula in Libre Office but couldn't make it work....but I found a different way - see my edited answer

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize this wasn't for Excel. If barry's answer works for you I will delete this answer

Answer (score 2):

In Excel this formula worked for me

`=INDEX(E$2:E$200,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(SQRT((C2-F$2:F$200)^2+(D2-G$2:G$200)^2)<1,0),0))`

That applies your equation to every pair in `F/G` compared against `C2` and `D2` - `MATCH` finds the first row where that value is `<1` and `INDEX` returns the required ID from column `E`

In Libre Office I couldn't make `MATCH` function work with the array but this version did as required:

`=INDEX(E$2:E$200,SMALL(IF(SQRT((C2-F$2:F$200)^2+(D2-G$2:G$200)^2)<1,ROW(F$2:F$200)-ROW(F$2)+1),1))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

In the latter formula your equation is evaluated for `C2` and `D2` against every row for the `F` and `G` values, if it returns a value < 1 then the `ROW(F$2:F$200)-ROW(F$2)+1`, returns the relative row number of that row in the range (e.g. row 2 is the first row so that would return 1, row 30 is the 29th row so that would return 29).

However many rows "match" `SMALL` will just return the smallest of those (`SMALL` function is preferable to `MIN` here because `MIN` will give a zero result if no rows match, it's better here to get an error in that case).

`INDEX` function then returns the corresponding value from that row

Comment: Way to stick with it and address the Libre Office problem :)

Comment: I suppose I should have mentioned I was working with LibreOffice to begin with. @barry, your excel formula works for me in Excel so at the very least I can do this part of my work on my home PC. Your LibreOffice Calc formula however returned whatever value was in column `E` i.e. it basically duplicated column `E` in column `B`. I was also trying to understand how that formula works, I'm not sure I follow: `ROW(F$2:F$200)` seems to return a value of 2 regardless of where in the column it is being evaluated and your `IF` statement is returning a value of `1` if it's true and `1` if it's false?

Comment: It sounds like you may not have confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER - if you do that correctly you will get "curly braces" like { and } around the formula - sometimes I had difficulty doing that in Libre Office - I had to go into the "Insert" option and tick the "array formula" box. I will add to to my answer to explain how that formula works

Comment: hi barry. CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER seemed to do nothing for me but your advice for Microsoft Excel worked fine.